# textfield with #disabled = true, #input = false

Tags: 7, forms

A textfield with #disabled = TRUE will appear greyed out, and be unchangeable.

A textfield with #input = FALSE will not send its value to $form_state['values'], and will be ignored by system_settings_form_submit().

Unfortunately, a textfield with #disabled = TRUE and #input = FALSE no longer appears greyed out.

I want to make a textfield that is purely for display purposes, so a person can copy a value from there. What is the best way to do this?

EDIT I: What I tried so far

To clarify, my starting point is code like this:

```
$form['thetext'] = [
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('The text'),
  '#disabled' => true,  // This should make it greyed out - but it doesn't due to #input = false below.
  '#input' => false,  // This should make this field ignored in $form_state['values'].
  '#value' => 'xyz',  // Either #value or #default_value.
];
```

EDIT II:

If this wasn't clear before: I really want the html output to be a textfield element. I also want to use the regular form + theme API, so that the element gets a label and wrapper div and theming like other form elements in the same form. E.g. if I would just hardcode the textfield html, it would no longer have the same classes, wrappers etc.

Comment: One might (quite reasonably) argue that from a semantics point of view, you shouldn't be using an `<input>` if you don't want, well, input :) Output is arguably better left to tags/structures that suit that were designed for it. Take Digital Ocean as an example: when you hover over stuff that's useful to be copied, but can't be edited, a "copy" link appears to the right. Implementing something like that would be more pretty simple (a class and a few lines of JS), and it might, again arguably, be more idiomatic and better UI/X

Comment: You have a point there.. but I somehow doubt that the reason why #input = false and #disabled = true don't combine well is a conscious design decision from Drupal developers :)

Comment: I think a good answer would start with your caveat about design considerations, then explain why #input = false seems to nullify #disabled = true, then show how it can be done despite this. Maybe by explicitly setting something in #attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Use a markup element instead.

```
$form['element'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => 'This is the thing you want people to see. You can use <strong>html</strong>, too.',
);
```

You don't actually have to specify `#type => 'markup'` because drupal defaults to that type if you don't specify, but I do anyway as it seems to be good practice.

Comment: But this does not appear as a text field. Of course I could hardcode the html into the #markup, but then it can no longer be themed..

Comment: Ah, well in that case I suppose you could just do '#default_value' => 'your value' for a regular text field. You don't have to disable it, just don't do anything with the value in the submit function.

Comment: But I want it to appear greyed out. And I want the input to be ignored, e.g. if I use system_settings_form() instead of a custom submit function. Of course I could add an additional submit handler that would unset the value form $form_state['values'].. but the goal was not to do that :)

Comment: That's a pretty specific idea... If I were doing it, I would probably use the markup type form element to code it manually so that it has the appearance of a textfield but isn't in $form or $form_state as such.

Answer (score 0):

## input = FALSE is redundant if #disabled = TRUE. Whatever value is in the field will already be ignored if #disabled = TRUE.